# Pretiier fails on auto save with SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Tags: javascript, angular, eslint, prettier

I have a problem with prettier config. I have added eslint to project, as well as prettier and eslint-config-prettier. I have added prettier as a file watcher to my WebStorm config file. But when I try to save file, prettier runs and fails with this error:

```
/Users/anjapopovic/Projects/docker/my-app/node_modules/.bin/prettier --write src/app/app.component.ts
/Users/anjapopovic/Projects/docker/my-app/node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js:6704
  return (x[0] - y[0]) ** 2 + (x[1] - y[1]) ** 2 + (x[2] - y[2]) ** 2;
                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also here is a WebStorm prettier setup:

Prettier config in WebStorm editor

[image]

If anyone encountered this error, it would be great if you could provide me insights :)

Comment: It’s possible that your version of node is too old to understand the exponentiation operator `**`, which prettier seems to use in its code base.
AFAIK, node 7 is the first version to support it.

Comment: No, i've already checked that. My node version is 12.16

Comment: What happens if you run prettier manually the same way WebStorm runs it? `./node_modules/.bin/prettier` and pass the same arguments?

Comment: When I run ```./node_modules/.bin/prettier --write src/app/home/home.page.ts```, he executes it without problem. It is an issue with WebStorm?

Comment: It's possible that WebStorm uses a different (older?) node executable.

Comment: Yes you are right, it was connected with node 6 version but although I fixed it, the behaviour is same.

Comment: Could be an override in the project settings (vs. global setting). JetBrains products are powerful but complicated…